# How to check the reason of changing the value of a column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

A column is updated and no one knows how it happens (the column name is `ClassCst` and it's values must be always 0 but unexpectedly it becomes 4).

By a query I found out this column is not updated due to a stored procedure.
Last night we updated the column value to 0, today at 9 am it was updated again to 4.

I would be grateful if you could help me in this matter

Comment: Please add a tag for database+version

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60 (X64)

Comment: Have you seen this QA ( http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/111517/find-the-identity-of-the-client-firing-a-query-in-sql-server-without-using-trigg )? You can also create an `ON UPDATE` trigger that logs client information. Also look at running SQL Server Profiler.

Answer (score 0):

Not guaranteed, but there is a chance to find it using the following query.

```
select      text

from                    sys.dm_exec_cached_plans                as cp
            cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(cp.plan_handle)    as st

where       text like '%ClassCst%'
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I sought  all this recommended query's result and there was no update for the column ClassCst , do you know another solution ? accually I searched all the job's steps by this query : SELECT j.name, js.*
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps js
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs j ON js.job_id = j.job_id
WHERE js.command LIKE '%customer%'         and unfortunately it had no result

Comment: Follow @Dai comment